# Blazor WebAssembly hosted on Azure AppService w/ EasyAuth blocking auth flow on unauthenticated return to site (when cached)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, blazor, azure-web-app-service, blazor-webassembly

I am having a very strange issue when using the Microsoft Identity Provider on an Azure Web App. I am using the ["Easy Auth"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) setup and everything works as intended 99.9% of the time except for a very specific scenario where I get a CORS policy issue. I suspect that this is actually NOT a CORS issue as a refresh will bypass this and continue the flow as expected. But for some reason it is being reported as one.

The Web App uses an App Registration that only allows users of the Entra/AD tenant to access the web app. Nothing fancy about my setup and it works as expected redirecting users to login via the [https://login.windows.net/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize](https://login.windows.net/%7BtenantId%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize) URL and then sending them back to the web app.

If you are already logged in this is bypassed (as expected) and you simply land on the content that is hosted. I use the `/.auth/me` path to extract the token from the JSON file that I then use to make API calls for the user. If this JSON file has expired I refresh the token but if it is absent I do a hard refresh in order to re-authenticate the user. In most cases this will start the authentication flow with Microsoft/Entra and then send the user back to the page they were attempting to load except in the case where the Blazor WASM interrupts the flow with a cached version of the files  on the client browser as outlined here.

**Here is the scenario:** If you have a cached version of the Blazor WASM site in your browser (meaning you have been to the site and have logged in prior) but you are completely signed out of your account (no refresh token available, etc) the Blazor WebAssembly project causes an interrupt in the authentication flow and is stuck on the initial loading page.

Basically it is stuck on the loading screen you get in the `wwwroot/index.html` page and does not get to `App.razor` in order to start the application.

To the user the page just seems to be stuck on the loading screen. If you refresh the browser the page then allows you to continue to the MS log-in flow and everything works as expected and no further issues occur. You can navigate away to another page and come back and as long as you are still signed into the tenant everything works as expected sometimes for days and weeks until your session ends and you need to re-authenticate in which case that initial load requires a refresh to get past again.

**Note:** I can force the issue to occur by using the: `/.auth/logout` URL which is what I have been using while debugging this issue.

**Note:** To make sure CORS was not an issue I added a record for all varations of the `_framework/blazor.boot.json` and `_framework/` paths to the AppRegistration allowed redirect URIs as well as the CORS settings on the WebApp and even to the "Allowed external redirect URLs" section on the WebApp Authentication Settings. I am sure that none of this was needed but did so in order to make sure I could check that off the box since these are being reported as issues by the browser (screenshots below).

**Here is what the browser is reporting when this issue occurs:**

With Blazor 7 WebAssembly:

**In my console output I get the following:**
[image]

**In my network output I get the following:**
[image]

With a Blazor 8 WebAssembly project (I've tried both) it is very similar:

**Console:**
[image]

**Network (Exactly the same):**
[image]

I suspected that the cached version of the Blazor WebAssembly App is trying to load content from the server from the client before authentication has occurred. Looking at the network logs The only page that is not cached is the **"blazor.boot.json"** file:

[image]

The client does try to hit this file right before the redirect to the authentication flow is started and this is the page that is being reported as the one that is tripping up the CORS policy so this is the likely culprit.

However this does not explain why a refresh bypasses the issue unless this is a race condition and a refresh allows the authentication flow to fire faster than the client has a chance to request that file?

I was looking for a way to delay the load but this seems like it is baked into the framework and happens before any code is run so it is not something I can likely control.

Telling users that have authenticated before to ***"just do a refresh"*** if the loader gets stuck is not exactly a good user experience so I am trying to smooth out this experience but  I've exhausted all my options to resolve this.

**UPDATE 1**

I noticed that if I add a unique query string variable (a cache buster) to the end of the URL it will bypass the cached version of the site and will go directly to the authentication flow without getting stuck on that loading screen. For example: `https://my-website.azurewebsites.net?cb=1234`

**UPDATE 2**

Since my scenario does a hard refresh of the site when the `/.auth/me` is absent I added a cache buster as a workaround so if the app itself requires a hard refresh (which is the most common scenario that was creating this issue) instead of using the same URL it appends the DatTime ticks to the end of the URL to make it unique:

```
var currentUri = _navigationManager.Uri;

// Add a cache buster to avoid caching issues blocking authentication flow
string cacheBuster = $"?cb={DateTime.Now.Ticks}"; 
if(currentUri.Contains("?"))
{
    cacheBuster = cacheBuster.Replace("?", "&");
}
currentUri = currentUri + cacheBuster;

_navigationManager.NavigateTo(currentUri, true); //<-- force a reload to re-authenticate
```

Not ideal but it works! A user can still create this situation on their own by navigating away from the site and then returning after their authentication expires but at least this mitigates issues when the site itself has control. If anyone knows of a way to bust the cache in other scenarios I would love to hear it. Perhaps there is a way to append a cache buster to the internal startup routine on a cached site?

Comment: I able to Authenticate without any issue. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/1iCxdWK.png)

Comment: But if you go to /.auth/logout and then try to return with a cached version of the app in your browser what happens?

Comment: I was successfully logout. [Image](https://i.imgur.com/3btbHL0.png)

Answer (score 0):

I added Microsoft Identity Provider to the Blazor Web Assembly hosted on Azure App Service. I successfully logged in and logged out without any issues..

**Program.cs**

```cs
using blazorAuth;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

**.csproj** :

```html
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="7.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="7.0.13" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I added Microsoft Identity Provider as shown below:

[image]

When I browse the web app URL, I got the following page for signing in:

[image]

Then, I selected my account for Sign In:

[image]

**Azure App Service Output**:

[image]

I added **`./auth/logout`** to the Azure web URL: **`https://<web-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/logout`**.

I got a page for logout. Then, I selected my account for logout.

[image]

I successfully logged out, as shown below:

[image]

Afterwards, I clicked on the **`RETURN TO THE WEBSITE`** button and refreshed the page, obtaining the following result:

[image]

I was successfully login again without any Issue.

[image]